# SwiftUI : How can I change the index from a view and show the correct Text in another view?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I don't understand why my `DetailView` is showing the same Text. (gif below)

Indeed I implemented a method selectTheme in `ContentView` that should change the selectedIndex according to the index of the row when the `DetailView` Appears but it seems that it does not take into account the var selectedIndex in my `ViewModel` remains 0.

Do you have any idea why? I really don't understand what going wrong here.

Thank you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var vm:ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(vm.sentences, id:\.self) { indexNumb in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(vm: vm).onAppear(perform: {
                        vm.selectTheme(sentence: indexNumb)
                        print(vm.groupedItems)
                        print("Array :\(vm.sylbArray)")
                        
                    })) {
                        Text(String(indexNumb))
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var vm:ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(vm.groupedItems,id:\.self) { subItems in
            HStack{
                
                ForEach(subItems,id:\.self) { word in
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print(vm.groupedItems)
                        print(vm.selectedIndex)
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text(word)
                    })
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ViewModel{
    
    @Published var sylbArray: [String] = []
    var groupedItems: [[String]] = []
    
    init() {
        appendArray(string: String(sentences[selectedIndex]))
        groupedItems = [sylbArray]
    }
    
    var sentences = [13,4]
    
    func appendArray(string: String) {
        sylbArray.append(string)
    }
    
//  remains  0 : why ? 
    var selectedIndex = 0
    
    func selectTheme(sentence: Int) {
        if let index = sentences.firstIndex(of: sentence) {
            selectedIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

[image: gif example]

Comment: `ObservableObject`s need to be observed using the appropriate wrapper https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject . Also, properties need to be marked `@Published` when you want views to redraw based not them

Answer (score 0):

Your viewModel must conform to class protocol 'ObservableObject'

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var sentences = [13, 4]
    @Published var selectedSentens: Int?
}
```

here is an example of what you want to do.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: ViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(vm.items, selection: $vm.selectedItem) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .tag(item)
            }
        } detail: {
            if let item = vm.selectedItem{
                DetailView(for: item)
            }
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}
```

item object:

```
struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var subItems: [String]
    var id = UUID()
}
```

viewModel class

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var items: [Item] = [
        Item(name: "Item 1", subItems: [ "sub 11", "sub 12" ] ),
        Item(name: "Item 2", subItems: [ "sub 21", "sub 22" ] )
    ]
    @Published var selectedItem: Item?
}
```

DetailView:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var item: Item
    init(for item: Item) {
        self.item = item
    }
    var body: some View {
        List(item.subItems, id: \.self){ subItem in
            Text(subItem)
        }
    }
}
```